# Visual Studio 2022 cannot build application

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-2022

When I try to build in vs22, it gives me an error that it cannot find some DLLs that have been added. But on VS19 the build works without problems.

I tried to change the build settings but no luck.

Error :
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error CS0006 Metadata file 'C:\xxxx\xxx\xxx\xxx.CMS.Service\bin\Debug\xx.CMS.Service.dll' could not be found xx.CMS.Frontend C:\xxx\xxx\xxx\xx.CMS.Frontend\CSC 1 Active

Comment: "it gives me an error that it cannot find some DLLs" - show us the error!

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0006 Metadata file 'C:\xxxx\xxx\xxx\xxx.CMS.Service\bin\Debug\xx.CMS.Service.dll' could not be found xx.CMS.Frontend C:\xxx\xxx\xxx\xx.CMS.Frontend\CSC 1 Active